# Swift3 adding a button Select / View in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm implementing a collectionView displaying images, when user selects one of the image, it opens the picture in largeMode.
Now I would need to add a button in the collectionView to let the user either select the view mode (as describe just above) or the select mode where the user can select multiple items for other purpose.

I tried to play with

> allowsMultipleSelection

when user selects the button but there is no effect.

How can I implement such feature ?

EDIT: adding some sample code

here is what I've tried:

```
    //button select mode
    @IBAction func Selection(_ sender: Any) {
    selectMode = !selectMode
    print("select mode is now: \(selectMode)")
    if(selectMode){
        self.navigationItem.title = "Selection de Photos"
        btnSelect.title = "Voir"
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=true 
    }
    else{
        self.navigationItem.title = "Gallerie"
        btnSelect.title = "Selection"
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=false
    }
}
```

and for the didselectitem

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection{
        print("multi selection mode activated, no preview")
    } else{
            _selectedCells.add(indexPath)
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(!selectMode){
        print("View mode")
        if(segue.identifier as! String == "viewLargePhoto"){
            let controller: ViewPhotoGallerie = segue.destination as! ViewPhotoGallerie
            let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for:sender as! UICollectionViewCell) as! NSIndexPath
            controller.index = indexPath.item
            controller.photosAsset = self.photosAsset
            controller.assetCollection = self.assetCollection
        }
    }
    else{
        print("Select mode")
    }
}
```

but if I'm in select mode (allowsMultipleSelection to false), the preview (segue) is launched and I'm not able to select multiple items.

EDIT2:

I've updated my code based on allowsMultipleSelection state, the segue to view image in large mode is still opened and then I'm not able to select multiple items. 
here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func Selection(_ sender: Any) {
    selectMode = !selectMode
    print("select mode is now: \(selectMode)")
    if(selectMode){
        btnSelect.title = "Voir"
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=true
    }
    else{
        btnSelect.title = "Selection"
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=false
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(!collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection){
        print("View mode")

        if(segue.identifier as! String == "viewLargePhoto"){
            let controller: ViewPhotoGallerie = segue.destination as! ViewPhotoGallerie
            let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for:sender as! UICollectionViewCell) as! NSIndexPath
            controller.index = indexPath.item
            controller.photosAsset = self.photosAsset
            controller.assetCollection = self.assetCollection
        }
    }
    else{
        print("Select mode")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of Selection mode you have to require to set `allowsMultipleSelection` as true.

```
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

To manage different action for selection and preview you can manage this using below condition

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection {
        //selection mode
    } else {
        // vide mode
    }
}
```

After completion selection mode set `allowsMultipleSelection` as false.

```
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

And find selected `indexPath` using.

```
for indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems! {

}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code (included in my initial question), but even if I set allowsMultipleSelection to true, the preview is opened, how can I disable the preview (launch viewController) to let the user select its items ?

Comment: You can use `if collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection` condition to identify the `view mode` or `selection mode`.

Comment: I tried to change my if statement in my prepare segue function and replace it with allowsMultipleSelection but the viewController is still called, is there any other call where the viewController is called ?

Comment: I've added the two functions linked

Comment: Looking every thing fine... But can you please check your `collectionView` IBOutlet connected with your collectionView layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178993/discussion-between-pratik-sodha-and-tiamat).

Comment: yes it is, my collectionView IBOutlet is correctly connected with my collectionView layout

Comment: Remove segue from `didSelect` :)

Comment: thanks pratik, I removed segue and made a pushViewcontroller manually

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW core funda is

1. You have to store each and every index on which user select any cell and remove that index from the array when user unselect that index.
2. When user clicks the button, every time you need to reload that cell and update the button status as selected or not.
3. When user clicks on `Submit/Preview` button, you need to use the array of index's to show the selected images.

If you unclear with the procedure then let me know.

Comment: thanks but this is ok, but I would need to let the user view the detailed image by default and only if end user selects the button "Multiple Select" to disable the viewController showing the detailed picture and let him selects multiple items

Comment: @tiamat I think you'r talking about the way native photos is doing. When user selects the `Select` then n only user can select the images. For this you need toggle the selection mode on the click of `Select` button. When user clicks on the `Select` button enable the selection mode else turn off selection. When selection mode is on you have to implement above procedure.

Comment: just added sample code in my initial question, hope it will be more clear